# Varnish Won't Start - "invalid number Cache"

Tags: vps, varnish

I wondered if anybody knew what would be causing Varnish to not start? The command and output is printed below. All I've done is download the latest version, set it up using yum, then edit a port number to 8888 instead of 80.

```
service varnish start
: invalid number Cache: /etc/init.d/varnish: line 54: ulimit: 131072
: invalid numberish: line 57: ulimit: 82000
: invalid numberish: line 61: ulimit: unlimited
                                                       [FAILED]
```

I'm running a CentOS 6.5 VPS, i686 i386 GNU/Linux.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems that init script can't raise the number of file descriptors, look at those lines in the init script and try to call those commands yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error today (someone asked the question on the Varnish IRC-channel).

The problem was that one of the configuration files for Varnish had CRLF-terminators in stead of LF.  Converting `/etc/default/varnish` with `dos2unix` solved the problem.